# Is there a way to refer to the entire matched expression in re.sub without the use of a group?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I want to prepend all occurrences of a particular expression with a character such as `\`.

In `sed`, it would look like this.

```
 echo '__^^^%%%__FooBar' | sed 's/[_^%]/\\&/g'
```

Note that the `&` character is used to represent the original matched expression.

I have looked through the [regex docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and the [regex howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html), but I do not see an equivalent to the `&` character that can be used to substitute in the matched expression.

The only workaround I have found is to use the an extra set of `()` to group the expression and then refernece the group, as follows.

```
import re


line = "__^^^%%%__FooBar"
print re.sub("([_%^$])", r"\\\1", line)
```

**Is there a clean way to reference the entire matched expression without the extra group creation?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Example:

```
>>> print re.sub("[_%^$]", r"\\\g<0>", line)
\_\_\^\^\^\%\%\%\_\_FooBar
```

Comment: You have really good eyes. I totally missed that sentence at the end of the paragraph. :) Will accept in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

You could get the result also by using [Positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) .

```
>>> print re.sub("(?=[_%^$])", r"\\", line)
\_\_\^\^\^\%\%\%\_\_FooBar
```